# Docker not forwarding http requests

Tags: scala, docker

I am running a Scala microservice application in my local docker container and trying to test it manually by using Postman but I am constantly getting a socket error:

```
Error: socket hang up
```

My application listens to 8080 port as main function contains:

```
  val bindingFuture = Http()
    .newServerAt("localhost", 8080)
    .bind(userRoute.route)
```

I am running my container by forwarding 8080 to 8080:

```
docker run -i -t -d -p  8080:8080 app-core:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

In container logs I see my application is up and running. Also, when I check with netstat, I see Docker is indeed listening to the 8080 port:

```
 netstat -na | Select-String "8080"

  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         127.0.0.1:59087        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         127.0.0.1:59088        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::1]:8080             [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

But for some reason, my http request is not being forwarded to the application. Any ideas?

Postman ss:
[image]

Main.scala:

```
    object Main extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem(Behaviors.empty, "hb-core-service-system")
  implicit val executionContext = system.executionContext
  val db = Database.forConfig("mydb")
  val userCommand: UserCommand = new UserCommand(db)
  val userRoute = new UserRoute(userCommand)

  val bindingFuture = Http()
    .newServerAt("127.0.0.1", 8080)
    .bind(userRoute.route)

  println(
    s"Server now online.\nPress RETURN to stop..."
  )

  StdIn.readLine() // let it run until user presses return
  bindingFuture
    .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
    .onComplete(_ => system.terminate()) // and shutdown when done
}
```

UserRoute.scala:

```
    class UserRoute(
    user: UserCommand
)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
    extends JsonFormats {

  def route: Route =
    pathPrefix("api" / "core-service") {
      Directives.concat(
        (path("create-user") & post)(createUser)
    }


  private def createUser: Route =
    entity(Directives.as[UserDto]) { dto =>
      complete {
        user.createUser(dto).map {
          case Some(id) =>
            id.asJson
          case None =>
            StatusCodes.BadRequest
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you checking for the requests being transferred (please add logs or screenshots)? can you share any reproducible code snippet, Dockerfile etc...? please add desktop environment like OS version etc...

Comment: Is having multiple entries for same port alright ?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli The route I am trying to test is basically doing an insert to database and returning an http response code. But since I get an socket error I assume it's not being forwarded to my app.

Comment: @sarveshseri what do you mean?

Comment: do you have any logs for the container? from what network context are you trying to call the container?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli The only log is the welcome message in the main function. I am trying to call it via http request with postman.

Comment: can you screenshot the output from postman and add more minimal reproducible code on the example

Comment: @NoamYizraeli I've updated the question.

Comment: do you get any more information when pressing *view in console*?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli Which console are we talking about? If it's Docker console, I don't see a view button.

Comment: next to the postman error

Comment: @NoamYizraeli No, only request body and request header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research I've realized the problem is basically with the following binding:

```
  val bindingFuture = Http()
    .newServerAt("localhost", 8080)
    .bind(userRoute.route)
```

It works perfectly until you put the application inside a docker container. When I changed "localhost" with "0.0.0.0", it started working as expected.